# html2pdf creates a blank PDF and somethings shows a security error 'The operation is insecure' on iOS 16.x.x

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

The html2pdf.js creates a Blank PDF or throws an error 'The operation is insecure' on new iOS 16.0.2.

Below is the html2pdf config:

```
function generatePDF(true) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var element = document.getElementById("main");
        
        var options = {
            filename: 'document.pdf',
            image: {
                type: 'jpeg',
                quality: 0.5
            },
            html2canvas: {
                scrollX: 0,
                scrollY: 0,
                scale: window.devicePixelRatio && window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 0.8 : 1
            },
            jsPDF: {
                unit: 'pt',
                format: 'a4',
                orientation: 'portrait'
            }
        };

        var pdf = html2pdf().set(options).from(element);

        pdf.outputPdf('datauristring').then(function(data) {
            // if (true)
            //     pdf.save();
            resolve({
                data: data.replace("data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64,", ""),
                type: "data:application/pdf"
            });
        }).catch(function(e) {
            alert('catch: ' + e);
            reject();
        });
    });
}
```

html2pdf.js version: 0.10.1
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.10.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js

I have noticed, 'scale' property of 'html2canvas' creates the security error.
However, the above code works in earlier version of iOS.

I wonder what am I missing out from the config?

Thanks